# Identifying the form elements from an HTML page

Tags: html, forms

Is there any way to find out whether there is a `<form></form>` tag in an HTML page (Using PHP and JQuery) and get the form? For example my page is `page.php` code below,

```
<html><body>
<h1> HAI TESTING</h1><h1> HAI TESTING  1 </h1>
<form name="test" method="post" id="test" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="radio" name="a" value="a"><input type="radio" name="a" value="b">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chekbox">
        <input type="email" name="email">
        <textarea>test</textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form></body></html>
```

From the above file `page.html`, I need to get this output:

```
<form name="test" method="post" id="test" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="radio" name="a" value="a"><input type="radio" name="a" value="b">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chekbox">
    <input type="email" name="email">
    <textarea>test</textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What programming (or scripting) language are you using? What format do you need to get this output in? Plain text? Parsed DOM fragment? Inner HTML of some element?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery then you can do this in the following way.

```
var form = $(document).find('form');
```

form variable will hold the desired output what you are looking for.

You can do this using javascript as well. Depends what you are using.

Comment: $filestring = file_get_contents($file); I am getting the file content using this code. I need to find the <form></form> tag from $filestring in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to find out whether there is a  tag in an HTML page (Using PHP and JQuery) and get the form?

I don't know much about PHP, but I do know that there's `document.forms` which returns a HTMLCollection of every `<form>` on a document. The following Snippet demonstrates how simple it is to find and collect `<form>` elements.

#### SNIPPET

Click <kbd>`Extract Forms`</kbd> to open, then <kbd>`Retract Display`</kbd> to close.

```js
function extractForm() {
  // Use document.forms method to collect <form>s.
  var fList = document.forms;
  // The .length property will return total number of <form>s in a given document.
  var fQty = fList.length;
  // Add text in <figcaption>
  document.querySelector('figcaption').textContent = 'There are ' + fQty + '  forms.';
  // Declare variables outside of loop.
  var display = document.querySelector('#display span');
  var HTML, i;
  // On every iteration, an item from fList will be extracted as a string then rendered as HTML.
  for (i = 0; i < fQty; i++) {
    HTML = fList[i].innerHTML;
    display.innerHTML += HTML;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 16px/1 Consolas;
}
a {
  display: block;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:first-of-type {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15%;
}
a:last-of-type {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15%;
}
#display {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -350px;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  transition: all 1s;
}
#display:target {
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  transition: all 1s;
}
#display span {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
figcaption {
  color: white;
  font: 16px/1 Consolas;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h1>HAI TESTING</h1>
  <form name="test" id="test1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>FORM 1</legend>
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <input type="radio" name="a" value="a">
      <input type="radio" name="a" value="b">
      <input type="checkbox" name="chekbox">
      <input type="email" name="email">
      <textarea>test</textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <form name="test" id="test2">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>FORM 2</legend>
      <input type="radio" name="a" value="a">
      <input type="radio" name="a" value="b">
      <meter></meter>
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <figure id="display">
    <figcaption></figcaption>
    <span></span>
  </figure>
  <a href="#display" onclick='extractForm()'>Extract Forms</a>
  <a href='#retractor'>Retract Display</a>


</body>

</html>
```